# How to use DateTime to round down the time by n minutes depending on the current time in the pc?

Tags: c#, winforms

```
DateTime RoundDown(DateTime date, TimeSpan interval)
        {
            return new DateTime(date.Ticks / interval.Ticks *
                interval.Ticks);
        }
```

using it

```
DateTime currentTime = RoundDown(DateTime.Now, TimeSpan.FromMinutes(-5));
```

but i want to add an option that it will check for the current pc time and if for example the time is 22:51 then round down to 22:50 meaning round down by 1.

so something like if i will call the method RoundDown like : RoundDown(); it will automatic check if to round down by 1 depending on the pc time.

if i will call it by : RoundDown(DateTime.Now, TimeSpan.FromMinutes(-5)); then it will round down by 5 or any number i give it.

Comment: Not tested, but it seems you are looking for something like this `DateTime RoundDown(){return RoundDown(DateTime.Now, TimeSpan.FromMinutes(-1))

Comment: Just so we're clear, I think you want it to go backwards in time to the nearest minute that is a MULTIPLE of 5? Will it always be in whole minutes? What about seconds? Should it first subtract 5 mins, and then round down?...or just go to the nearest 5 min interval that is smaller?

Comment: @Idle_Mind to the nearest 5 and only minutes.  for exmaple if the time is  22:51 then down by one to 22:50 if the time is 22:39 down to 22:35 and if it's 22:11 down to 22:10 the first time it should check the current time and then to decide automatic if to down by 5 or first to down to the nearest rounded time.

Comment: @Idle_Mind you right.  and only the minutes is matter for now. maybe later it will be nice to extend it also to seconds as option but for now i want to care about the minutes.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That would just be:

```
  public static void Main (string[] args) {
    Console.WriteLine(RoundDown(DateTime.Now, 5));
  }

  public static DateTime RoundDown(DateTime dt, int NearestMinuteInterval)
  {
    return new DateTime(dt.Year, dt.Month, dt.Day, dt.Hour, dt.Minute / NearestMinuteInterval * NearestMinuteInterval, 0);
  }

  public static DateTime RoundUp(DateTime dt, int NearestMinuteInterval)
  {
    return (new DateTime(dt.Year, dt.Month, dt.Day, dt.Hour, 0, 0)).AddMinutes((dt.Minute / NearestMinuteInterval + 1) * NearestMinuteInterval);
  }
```

Comment: what would be the formula if i want to round up instead round down ?

Comment: I added a `RoundUp()` (untested). See if that works for ya...

Comment: Operator '*' cannot be applied to operands of type 'DateTime' and 'int'

Comment: Sorry. Messed up the parenthesis.